# scrolltop jquery method not working

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a button:

```
<a href="#" id="sign-in-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg more-site">Sign In</a>
```

and this jquery statement

```
@Html.Script(@<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#sign-in-btn").click(function () {
        $(window).scrollTop($('#whatda').offet().top);
    });
})
</script>)
```

which I had hoped would scroll down to a div container I have mentioned later in the page which is this:

```
<div class="home-top" id="whatda">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.Partial(...)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason though, it doesn't scroll down to this section when the button is clicked and has always been scrolling to the same point no matter what. Is there something wrong with this code sample? Could it be something engraved into the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sign-in-btn").click(function () {                


     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#whatda').offset().top
    }, 500);               
    });
})
```

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/3carvksw/